# For how long I can use bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have lot of bootstrap 3 html template. I can not convert them to bootstrap 5.

MY questions : For how long I can use bootstrap 3?

Comment: As long as you like. It's not going to stop working anytime soon.

Comment: You should keep in mind that [Bootstrap 3 is end-of-life](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2019/07/24/lts-plan/) since July 2019 and doesn’t get security updates anymore.